# FATAL ERROR - PHP cURL

Tags: php

*Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Users\aprendiz151ciee\Desktop\PHP - WebServer\root\DASHBOARD\arquivo.php on line 62*

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\aprendiz151ciee\Desktop\PHP - WebServer\root\DASHBOARD\arquivo.php on line 145

**Alguém sabe o por que deste erro?!** 

Em casa funciona perfeitamente, chega na empresa... Acontece este erro. Deve ser por que em casa eu uso o XAMPP com o PHP 7.1 e aqui no trabalho eu utilizo o [USB WEBSERVER](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/)?

```html
<?php


$x = new Nulogy();
$retorno = $x->iniciar();
echo $retorno;

class Nulogy{

public $u;
public $s;
public $url;
public $post;
public $resposta;
public $cookie;
public $token;
public $urlDownload;
public $dir;
public $nome;
public $ds;
public $arquivo;
public function __construct(){

  $this->u = 'login';
  $this->s = 'senha';
  $this->dir = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'download'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $this->cookie = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '/cookie/' .'NULOGY[COOKIE]' . rand(0, 999999) . '.txt'; 
}
public function iniciar(){
  $this->url = 'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in';
  $this->loginPlayLoad();
  $this->post();
  $validarLogin = $this->validarLogin();
  if($validarLogin === 'logado'){
  return $this->linkDownload();
  }else{
    return $validarLogin;
  }
}
public function loginPlayLoad(){
  $this->getTokenLogin();
  if($this->token){
    $data['utf8'] = '✓';
    $data['authenticity_token'] = $this->token;
    $data['return'] = '';
    $data['uv_login'] = '';
    $data['user[login]'] = $this->u;
    $data['user[password']= $this->s;
    $data['commit'] = 'Sign in';
    $data['authenticity_token'] = $this->token;
    $data['authenticity_token'] =$this->token;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
  $this->post = http_build_query($data);
  return true;
}
public function getTokenLogin(){
  $this->url = 'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in';
  $this->get();
  preg_match_all('/meta content="(.*?)" name="csrf-token"/', $this->resposta, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
  $token = $matches[0][1];
  if($token){
    return $this->token = $token;
  }else{
    return array('status' => false,'resposta' => 'Não foi possível encontrar CSRF-TOKEN' );
  }
  return false;
}
public function validarLogin(){
  if(preg_match_all('/title>(.*?)<.title>/', $this->resposta, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)){
    $titlo = $matches[0][1];
  }else{
  $titlo = false;
  }  

  if((isset($titlo) && ($titlo === 'Sign in to PackManager') )) {
    return $titlo . ' Login ou senha inválidos.'; 
  }else{
    return 'logado';
  }
}
public function linkDownload(){
  $url = [
  'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/canned_reports/job_productivity?utf8=%E2%9C%93&generate_flag=true&filter_choice=project_customer&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Boperator%5D=between&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bfrom_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-2+9%3A00+PM&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bto_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-3+11%3A46+PM&columns%5B0%5D=project_code&columns%5B1%5D=item_code&columns%5B2%5D=actual_job_start_at&columns%5B3%5D=actual_job_end_at&columns%5B4%5D=line_name&columns%5B5%5D=performance&columns%5B6%5D=availability&columns%5B7%5D=line_efficiency&columns%5B8%5D=units_produced&columns%5B9%5D=units_expected&columns%5B10%5D=unit_of_measure&columns%5B11%5D=standard_units_per_hour&columns%5B12%5D=duration&order_by=actual_job_start_at&order_direction=desc&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&format=csv',
  'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/jobs.csv?authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&customer_name=&from_scheduled_start_at=2017-Jul-2+00%3A00&has_production=all&item_code=&line_leader=all&line_leader_id=all&line_name=&page=1&project_code=&reconciliation_status=all&signed_off=no&status=all&to_scheduled_end_at=2017-Jul-3+23%3A59&utf8=%E2%9C%93',
  'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/canned_reports/job_downtime?utf8=%E2%9C%93&generate_flag=true&filter_choice=item_class_name&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Boperator%5D=between&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bfrom_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-2+9%3A00+PM&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bto_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-3+11%3A55+PM&columns%5B0%5D=job_id&columns%5B1%5D=line_name&columns%5B2%5D=downtime_reason_code&columns%5B3%5D=downtime_reason_name&columns%5B4%5D=downtime_duration&columns%5B5%5D=downtime_notes&order_by=actual_job_start_at&order_direction=desc&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&format=csv'];
  $nome = [0 => 'produtividade do trabalho.csv',1 => 'Trabalhos.csv' , 2 => 'inatividade do trabalho.csv'];
  $i = 0;

  foreach($url as $u):
    $this->urlDownload = $u;
    $this->nome = $nome[$i++];
    echo $this->dw();
  endforeach;
}
public function header(){
  $header = [
      "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
      "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
      "Connection: keep-alive",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ];
  return $header;
}
public function dw(){
    $this->url = $this->urlDownload;
    $this->get();
    $dw = $this->resposta;
    $this->arquivo = $this->dir.$this->nome;
    if($this->arquivosExiste()){
      
    file_put_contents($this->arquivo , $dw);
    $ret =  'Arquivo salvo na pasta: ' . $this->dir . '<br>';    
    }else{
      $ret = 'Algum problema foi encontrado :/';
    }
    return $ret;
}
public function arquivosExiste(){
  if (is_file($this->arquivo)){
      unlink($this->arquivo);
   }
  return true;
}
public function post(){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header());
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
  $this->resposta = curl_exec($ch);
}
public function get(){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header());
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
  $this->resposta = curl_exec($ch);
}
}
```

Comment: A mensagem está te dizendo que excedeu o tempo limite de execução. Provavelmente na sua empresa deve ter alguma regra de firewall ou proxy que não te deixa navegar em tal site. Já verificou se consegue acessar tudo que precisa sem ser pelo php?

Comment: Pô, pra falar a verdade aqui proibi muitos sites. Aparece esta imagem aqui: https://prnt.sc/fyhpwv
Mas o site que eu acesso nesse código, é liberado pelo sistema. É o site que usamos para ver a produção.

Comment: Então no caso devo entrar em contato com eles para liberar o meu acesso?! Mas o que devo pedir para liberar? Se o site que eu acesso pra fazer os download de arquivos CSV é liberado...

Comment: Então está aí seu problema. Se é algo para o trabalho em si, entre em contato com o pessoal que administra a rede do seu ambiente de trabalho e explique que precisa acessar tal site. Pode ser bloqueio http, https, ftp, etc. Tem que ver o que você precisa e qual serviço precisa e alinhar isso com a rede do seu ambiente de trabalho.

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado Fernando!